Bifurcation classification
I have an exercise where I have to sketch the bifurcation diagram and classify the ocurring bifurcations for 1-D ODEs. I have doubts on the following ones:
\begin{align}
x' & = \mu - \sin(x)\tag{1}\label{1}
\\[1mm]
x' & = \mu^2 - x^2\tag{2}\label{2}
\end{align}
As much as I would like to show my bifurcation diagrams, I cannot since I am limited by my $\LaTeX$ ability. I can describe them, however.

For (\ref{1}) I get a sideways sine wave where the x-axis ranges from $-1 \le \mu \le 1$ and the y-axis from $-\pi \le x < \pi $. To better get the picture; at $\mu = 1$ I have $x = \frac{\pi}{2}$; at $\mu = 0$ I have $x = \{\pi, 0, -\pi\}$; at $\mu = -1$ I have $x = -\frac{\pi}{2}$.

How do I even classify this bifurcation? We have seen saddle-node, heteroclinic, pitchfork bifurcations, but I cannot seem to recognizeany of such in this case.


Likewise for (\ref{2}), from which I get two sideways parabolas both with their "minimum" at $\mu = 0$. The bifurcation diagram has a similar shape to $x$. In this case, if you start "reading" from $0$ towards the positive numbers, it looks like a supercritical saddle-node. Starting from $0$ towards the negative numbers, a subcritical saddle-node. So which one is it? Can it be both?

I apologize for not being able to display my bifurcation diagrams. Any feedback is appreciated!

It would really help if you could add the images. I think there might be issues with both but will concentrate on the second system here because it's easier to describe. Your bifurcation diagram is a plot of the equilibria in the $(x,\mu)$ plane, on which you can indicate stability. To find the equilibria, you solve $\mu^2-x^2=0$, which definitely doesn't give you a parabola (or pair of them). Once you've got the graph, you can figure out the stability either graphically or by looking at the derivative of $f(x)=\mu^2-x^2$ at the equilibria.

@ChrisLewis I have made a mistake, the x-axis is $\mu$ and the y-axis $x$. Apologies for the confusion. I have edited it now. Also, I did not mean parabola (my mistake as well). Rather, the bifurcation diagram looks like an "X". This I am pretty sure is correct since $\mu = \pm x$, which should inevitably yield an "X" diagram with the midpoint being $x = 0$.

Yes, it looks like an X. Did you get the stability? As for the type of bifurcation, it's not one of the ones you've listed in your question, but I'm surprised it's not in that list (it'd normally be one you'd learn soon after the saddle-node bifurcation).

@ChrisLewis Oh right, its a transcritical bifurcation!
